# SQL to map users after registering

Tags: sql

I have a table A. When the user comes in our website, the id will be null. after they register, the id will be generated. How do I track the customer from the time they land .

```
id   time       city     ipaddresss      page visited
     10.15   New York    192.45.323.12    page1
     10.4    New York    192.45.323.12    page2
1    11.15   New York    192.45.323.12    page3
1    11.45   New york    192.45.323.12    page3
```

so this is a single customer's data. When the ipaddress is same, the user id which is null also needs to be taken, when i do analysis.How do I map them?.

Comment: Why don't you generate the ID before creating the first record for a new user?

Comment: Or use the IP address as the identifier?

Comment: This is event data from a analytics platform. Before a user registers, thier id is null. I need to join this table to multiple tables. so user id is the identifier.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your data suggests that you have one user per ip address.  That does not seem realistic, but with that assumption you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(id,
                max(id) over (partition by ipaddress)
               ) as imputed_id
from t;
```

Strictly speaking the `coalesce()` is not necessary, but it highlights why the window function is being used.

When I've encountered this issue, it has been much more complicated, because sessions need to be taken into account -- and some IP addresses have multiple users.  If that is closer to the problem you are really trying to solve, then ask *another* question with more appropriate data and a better explanation of what you need to do.

Comment: Hi, exactly its not as simple as I posted. I am creating a session table. And yes, some ip address have multiple users and vice versa. I am really confused how to handle this. Can you please explain me more on this. It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: @George . . . Please ask another question with more appropriate sample data and desired results.  I believe this answers the question that you asked here.